# How can I use javascript to put the same XML tags into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

So basically what's happening is that my code will be reaching a server via AJAX and recieving the response in XML. What I'm trying to do is decipher all of the 'displayName' tags.

```
<displayName>
     <![CDATA[Name]]>
</displayName>
<displayName>
     <![CDATA[Some other name]]>
</displayName>
```

What I've been tried so far is on the lines of this: NOTE: variable result is the xml response

```
$('displayName' result).text();
```

Which gives me something like this: "NameSome other name"

I want it to be in an array instead.
What do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
var arr = [];
$('displayName' result).each(function(i){
    arr.push($(this).text());
})
```